# How to get authenticated user info in a JAX-WS web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

How can I get authenticated user info from JAX-WS Web Service?

Thanks

Comment: Short question - short answer: use `WebServiceContext` injection: http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/MessageContext.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't know how to mark the question as answered as @home answered the question as a comment.

Anyhow, following is the answer

```
@WebService()
public class MyWebService{
  @Resource
  private WebServiceContext wsContext;
  @WebMethod
  public void echoHello(String msg) {
    System.out.println("Username = " + wsContext.getUserPrincipal().getName());
  }
}
```